# 500 Internal Server Error When Importing Python Modules

Tags: python, tensorflow, web, cgi

I'm new to web development with Python, so this problem might be silly.

I'm trying to run a Python script on my web server, but i'm encountering  a problem when importing some modules.

The script works fine when writing a simple script like this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print("This is a test")
```

And i can import most of the modules installed in the Python version of the server, but when i try to import some modules i really need for my script, i get a 500 Internal server error (these modules are tensorflow, keras and scikit-image). So this code gives a 500 error:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import keras
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print("This is a test")
```

I tried to print all the modules installed in the Python version with pip.get_installed_distributions() and all three modules i need, keras, tensorflow and scikit-image are installed.

My questions are:

- How can i print the error to understand what the problem is?
- What could be the problem considering that the packages are installed but not working?

Comment: Try checking the logs.They could provide you with insights into the problem.

Comment: May sound like a stupid question, but how can i look at the logs? Where do i find them? On my local PC i was just gonna run the python script on a python environment, but i can't do that on the web server

Comment: Are you using a web host for your web server?

Comment: Yes, currently using Heliohost with cPanel

Comment: [This](https://wiki.helionet.org/Solving_Internal_Server_Errors) could help.